# Looking for a way to delete multiple columns from multiple tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have around 300 tables, each of which had 7 columns added during processing. The names of these columns are the same in each table. We no longer have a use for these columns and must remove them. Is there a way to remove these columns from all tables I specify in batch?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you run a (single) `select` statement that retrieves all table names?

Comment: I Wasn't sure how to approach this so I just tried "Alter Table" and listed the table names, separated by commas. Then "Drop Column" followed by the list of columns (again separated by commas). But I just got a syntax error pointing at the first comma separating table names.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the shotgun approach and do something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION alter_tables() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    table_record RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR table_record IN SELECT table_name::TEXT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema = '<SCHEMA_NAME>' LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_record.table_name || ' DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS <COLUMN_NAME> CASCADE;';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT alter_tables();
DROP FUNCTION alter_tables();
```

Replace `<SCHEMA_NAME>` and `<COLUMN_NAME>` as appropriate.

This will (obviously) not work if you need to be more selective about the exact set of tables to alter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**information_schema**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/information-schema.html) set of views for this task. You are interested in [**columns**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/infoschema-columns.html) view in particular. Sample code might be the following:

```
-- test DDL
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 INTEGER,col2 INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE table2 (col1 INTEGER,col2 INTEGER);

-- possible function definition
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_columns(schema_to_process TEXT,column_list TEXT[]) RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  column_record RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR column_record IN
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns AS cinfo
    WHERE cinfo.table_schema = $1
    AND cinfo.column_name = ANY($2)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || $1 || '.' || column_record.table_name || ' DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS ' || column_record.column_name || ' CASCADE;';
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- sample run
SELECT delete_columns('public',ARRAY['col2']);
```